TemplateSyntaxError after Adding Django Admin Theme using Jazzmin Module
I've added a Django admin panel theme to my project using the django-jazzmin module. It works fine initially, but when I try to access certain options in the admin panel (like "Users" or "Profile"), I encounter the following error:
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/booking/bookedseat/53/change/ Invalid filter: 'length_is'
and this is my html code
   <div class="form-group{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if not line.has_visible_field %} hidden{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
From what I've read online, it seems like the theme might be deprecated or not fully compatible with Django 5, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm currently stuck and not sure how to resolve this issue.
Has anyone else faced this problem? Any advice on how to fix this template error or suggestions for alternative themes that work well with Django 5?
Details:
Django version: 4.2
Jazzmin version: django-jazzmin-3.0.0
Thanks in advance for any help!
Questions:
Has anyone encountered this issue with Jazzmin on Django 5?
Is there a known fix or workaround to resolve this length_is filter error while still using Jazzmin?
Would downgrading Django or making adjustments to the Jazzmin templates be a viable solution?

There are two solutions  that have worked for me.

One is downgrading from Django==5.1 to Django==5.0
add this in @register.filter(name="length_is") def length_is(value: Any, length: str | int) -> bool: return len(value) == int(length) in the jazzmin.py found in the lib/python3.11/site-packages/jazzmin/templatetags in my virtual environment adjust the python version with yours.

I hope this helps you.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The issue is that starting from version 5.1, some template tags that are currently used in the Django-Jazzmin admin panel have been removed. Because of this, you are encountering exceptions.
You can either downgrade to an earlier version of Django or manually adjust the templatetags in Django-Jazzmin to avoid exceptions caused by the removal of these template tags in newer versions.
Lib/site-packages/jazzmin/templatetags/jazzmin.py and just add this code
@register.filter(name='length_is')
def length_is(value, arg):
    return len(value) == int(arg)

